# epsilon delta proof for 2 variable limit

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Hey I need to show that $$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}  {xy \over \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}} = 0.$$ I'm not sure how to start manipulating this as I haven't gotten anything useful yet. Some help to get me going would be nice. Thanks

Comment: I love when the question asked 5 years ago matches my homework exactly ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notice that $$|x| = \sqrt{x^2} \le \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$$
 Using this fact, we have
$$\left\vert\frac{xy}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}\right\vert = \frac{|x|}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}|y|\le |y|$$
which approaches $0$ as $(x,y)\rightarrow 0$.

It should not be too hard to convert this into a formal epsilon-delta proof.

Answer (score 5):

Let $$f(x,y) = \dfrac{xy}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}$$
Set $x = r \cos(\theta)$, $y = r \sin(\theta)$, let $\sqrt{x^2 + y^2} = r$. $$F(r,\theta) = f(r \cos(\theta), r \sin(\theta)) = \dfrac{r^2 \cos(\theta) \sin(\theta)}{r} = r \cos(\theta) \sin(\theta)$$
$$(x,y) \to (0,0) \implies r \to 0$$
Now can you conclude what you want?

Comment: Yes, but this is not using epsilon-delta

Comment: @William: But this is a very formal approach (+1). :)