# Epsilon-delta proof at incorrect limit point

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

I know that $$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}  {xy^2 \over \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}(x^2 + y^2)} \ne 0.$$

However, when I try to (wrongly) prove that the limit does equal $0$, using $$|x|, |y|, y  \le \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$$ (I do realise that this is bad notation, not sure how I could write it here in a different way without using 3 equations), I get $$\left\vert\frac{xy^2}{(x^2 + y^2)^{3/2}} - 0\right\vert = \frac{|x|}{(x^2 + y^2)^{3/2}}y^2\le \frac{y^2}{(x^2 + y^2)} = \frac{|y||y|}{(x^2 + y^2)}\le $$

$$\frac{|y|}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}\le |y|\le \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}< \delta < \epsilon$$

Since $$||(x,y)-(0,0)||= \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}< \delta$$

It's somewhat based on [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/202555) answer.
So now I wonder, at what step do I make a mistake, since this should (as far as I know) not be possible?

Edit: If it has to do with dividing by zero, then why is that not a problem in the linked answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake seems to be

$$\frac{|y|}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}} \leq |y|$$

Try $x = y = .5$ and get

$$\frac{.5}{\sqrt{.5}} \leq .5$$

But $\sqrt{.5} > .5$.

Comment: If $x = y = .5$ then $x^2 = y^2 = .25$ so $x^2 + y^2 = .5$.  The inequality does not hold.

Comment: Oh, my bad. Erased that post

Comment: @Jim Thank you, that is indeed the mistake. I really need to get better at not making such mistakes, I guess it comes with practice.